# How to align Shapeless records?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given

```
case class Foo(a: Int, c: Int)
case class Bar(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)
```

I would like to write a function which looks something like:

```
def mkBar(foo: Foo, b: Int): Bar = {
  import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

  val fooRecords = LabelledGeneric[Foo].to(foo)
  val bRecord = 'b ->> b
  val allRecords = fooRecords :+ bRecord

  // Doesn't work as it's a c b and we need a b c
  LabelledGeneric[Bar].from(allRecords)
}
```

i.e. Given a Foo and a b, create a Bar. This code doesn't compile as I've appended "b" instead of inserting it in the middle of the Hlist.

I know I can use an `hlist.Align` to align to a `Bar` but all the examples I have seen show two Reprs e.g. `Align[FooGen.Repr, BarGen.Repr]`. In my case I don't have a Repr for the `allRecords` instance so I don't know how to derive a suitable Align instance.

How can I align an "on the fly" Hlist to a Repr?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was to split the code into another function with a type parameter and implicit Align instance. In the end I came up with this:

```
object ShapelessOps {

  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.ops.hlist

  trait Converter[A, B] {
    def apply(a: A): B
  }

  implicit class ConverterOps[A](a: A) {
    def as[B](implicit converter: Converter[A, B]): B = converter.apply(a)
  }

  implicit def genericConverter[B, BRepr <: HList, Unaligned <: HList](
    implicit
    bGen    : LabelledGeneric.Aux[B, BRepr],
    align   : hlist.Align[Unaligned, BRepr]
  ): Converter[Unaligned, B] = new Converter[Unaligned, B] {
    def apply(a: Unaligned): B = bGen.from(align.apply(a))
  }

}
```

And I use it like:

```
val fooRecords = LabelledGeneric[Foo].to(foo)
val bRecord = 'b ->> b
val allRecords = fooRecords :+ bRecord
allRecords.as[Bar]
```